# fileOffset empty in Data Loss Prevention results for PDF and DOCX files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I configured a DLP inspection job using GCP Console to scan PDF and DOCX files. It is working as expected, finding the expected entities and saving results to a BigQuery table.

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/supported-file-types#scanning_modes), DLP uses Intelligent Document Parsing for PDF and DOCX. This should give me additional location details in a [DocumentLocation](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/InspectResult#DocumentLocation) object.

I can see column `location.content_locations.document_location.file_offset` in the BigQuery table, but **it is empty**.

I am getting `location.byte_range` values for TXT files and `location.content_locations.image_location.bounding_boxes` for images, but **no location information for documents**.

What can be causing this issue?

Comment: It's a bug and being worked on.

Comment: If you can add a reference to a ticket in some bug tracker (mine is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173488142) - should I close it?), you can post your comment as an actual answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Within the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/173488142), an internal communication channel was added with the engineering team to notify the progress of the mitigation of this issue. I suggest you subscribe to it, by clicking on the star next to the title, to keep updated and receive emails regarding its progress.

Comment: @Orlandog What's you preference - should I use SO or the tracker for such questions? I ran into another potential bug.

Comment: Public issue tracker (PIT) is used to report bugs or feature requests related to some Google Cloud Platform products; therefore, if you consider that you finding is a bug or a feature request, open a PIT.

Comment: On the other hand, questions with ‘google-cloud-platform’ tags and product-specific tags (such as ‘google-bigquery’) are monitored by Google engineers and by the community. Also, some findings that we think are bugs actually have some workaround; thus, if you consider that you have probably overlooked something or would like to get either help or the opinion of the community, I recommend you open a Stack Overflow post.